# Problems Deploying a hosted WCF Service in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service

I have a WCF Service which I am hosting in a windows service. The Windows host service has an App.config to consume a service endpoint and the service has an App.config which exposes the metadata endpoints. When the service is deployed via the VS development system it all works great. With a Web Browser loaded, the http://localhost:9001/ url resolves to the metadata webpage exposing the wsdl link for the service. It even works with the WCF Test Client as well and I can send the service messages and it responds.

However, with the projectInstaller loaded on the hosted service in VS and deployed outside of the VS development system, I can no longer access the http://localhost:9001/ metadata endpoint when the hosted service is deployed in Windows. The service is started and running, but the endpoint doesn’t respond. The Service is deployed from the debug folder using the “sc create binpath= “Service.exe” start= auto” command. Maybe this is not the correct way to deploy it, not sure or maybe my app.Config files are not correct or being referenced correctly. Could someone let me know the process for this and maybe verify that my app.Config files are correct for both the windows Host and Service side. This is pretty tricky to configure, so any help is appreciated.

Window host service App.config to consume the endpoints:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
    </client>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding_WindowsService" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
        <!-- Service endpoint to consume -->
        <service name="WindowsService.Service">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:9001/Service" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                contract="WindowsService.IService" />
        </service>
    </services>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Service Web.config to expose the endpoints:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding_WindowsService" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultbehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="defaultbehavior" name="WindowsService.Service">
          <!-- Base address for exposing Metadata and Service -->
          <host>
            <baseAddresses>
              <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9001/" />
            </baseAddresses>
          </host>

          <!-- Metadata service endpoint to expose -->
          <endpoint address="" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          <!-- Service contract endpoint to expose -->
          <endpoint address="Service" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WindowsService.IService" />
        </service>
    </services>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Bounce... Can anyone help w/ this.

Comment: Two app.config files look suspicious. How many processes do you run? What is the difference between "host service" and "service"? If this is one process, then they should share same app.config file.

Comment: I have a self hosting service with console app using the ServiceBase class to start/stop the service. The web service is the actual service that the host controls and it has a Web.config. I was told that I would need an App.config for the console app that is hosting the windows service to consume the customers endpoints and the Web.config for the WCF service to expose the endpoints to the customer, is that not true and the App.config will work for both?  Maybe the Web.config is only needed for IIS .svc type services and not self hosted ones. Could you let me know?

Comment: `web.config` is useless here, as the Windows service won't load it at all.

Comment: @LexLi is correct. You need single app.config that your service will use  - it may contain both metadata endpoints and service endpoints.